# How to parse given string format to dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:aa?

Tags: java, date, datepicker

I can get the output as `Wed May 11 15:36:08 IST 2016`, but how do I convert the date to a string with the required format?

Required format is: `12-05-2016 16:05:08 pm`

What I tried is,

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
        String epoche="1462961108000";
        Long initialLogTime = Long.valueOf(epoche);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(initialLogTime);
        Calendar fromDateTime = calendar;
        Calendar toDateTime = fromDateTime;
        toDateTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:aa");
        String datestring = String.valueOf(fromDateTime.getTime());
        String datestring1 = String.valueOf(toDateTime.getTime());
        System.out.println(datestring); //here output is Wed May 11 15:36:08 IST 2016
        System.out.println(datestring1); // here output is Wed May 11 15:36:08 IST 2016
        Date dates = dateFormat.parse(datestring);
        Date date1s = dateFormat.parse(datestring1);
        System.out.println(dates);
        System.out.println(date1s);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 11 16:05:08 IST 2016"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a string then parsing, when you already *have* the value? It's unclear what the ultimate aim is here... (If it's just to format the value as a string, you shouldn't be calling `parse` at all.)

Comment: As pointed out, `SimpleDateFormat` should be called using the method `format()` on the `Date` object, not `parse()` on the `String` object, to get your required result

Comment: If you are using the SimpleDateFormat, take into account that it's a formatter. It can parse and format. Parsing means you convert to a type instance like for example a Date. Formatting means you are essentially converting it into a readable form, normally in the form of a String. In your case you already have a date and so you don't need any intermediate step as you were trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to format your dates accordingly. This shall help you

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:aa");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(fromDateTime.getTime()));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(toDateTime.getTime()));
```

Comment: your format `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:aa` gives output `11-May-2016 15:35:08:PM`

Comment: @ankur-singhal The api doesn't seem to provide an alternative to lower case [SimpleDateFormat]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), so I'd suggest just to replace the uppercase PM/AM to lowercase maybe by search and replace or splitting.

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha i was actually pointing at `May` instead of `05`

Comment: @ankur-singhal now it will give `05`.. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java 8, you can use

LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:aa");

System.out.println(date.format(formatter));

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String epoche = "1462961108000";
        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(epoche));
        DateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:aa");
        String strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
```

**Output**

```
11-05-2016 15:35:08:PM
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, **Pass String Like 11/10/2017 11:16:46** to function **ConvertDateTime**

```
   public String ConvertUpdate(String strDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy hh:mm a");

        return simpleDateFormat.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> output
>   10 Nov 17 11:16 AM